# Transferring arbitrary objects from one service to another via http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to transfer an arbitrary object from one service to another via a http get request, but I'm having trouble deserializing it on the client side.

For example, given this endpoint on the first service:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public ActionResult<HttpRequestMessage> Get()
{
    using var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\data.tar", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

    var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    formDataContent.Add(fileContent, "file", "data.tar");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5000/upload") { Content = formDataContent };


    return Ok(request);

}
```

How can I call this endpoint from the second service and recreate the HttpRequestMessage object?

To get a response I would call the endpoint like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5432/api/test");
```

But I cant figure out how to manipulate this response object into  a HttpRequestMessage object

Comment: Most objects are not really serializable... Make sure to limit your transfer to types that actually make sense in serialized state... `HttpRequestMessage` is not expected to be serialized so don't expect much useful outcomes with sending it...

Comment: So you cant transfer most objects via http between two dot net apps? Huh, that's surprising